# Yii как проверить доступность страницы?

Tags: yii

Предположим у каждого пользователя есть роль. Роли соответствуют ид страниц.
Для внешних ссылок я сделал такую проверку (грузится во фрейм). Перед загрузкой смотрю есть в таблице haspage (сводная таблица - id роли, id страницы) запись и в зависимости от этого отображаю или нет.
Но вот для внутренних ссылок я храню относительный путь типа (site\index, page\admin) и прочее. Сделать бы какой нить blockpost.php , чтобы при запросе к любой странице проверялась роль, есть ли у неё права для отображения ?

upd

предположим я могу проверить линк таким образом (псевдокод)

```
$page = Userpage::model->find(id_role = yii->id_role))
foreach ($page as $row)
{
if ($row->link == $this_link)
render($this_link)
else echo 'нет прав'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделала через событие `Application::EVENT_AFTER_REQUEST`, в котором проверяю соответствие запрашиваемой страницы и роли.

Вот ссылка

https://github.com/developeruz/yii2-db-rbac/blob/master/behaviors/AccessBehavior.php

Comment: так а для yii это подойдет? я не очень понимаю что там написано...

Comment: Это написано на Yii2. Суть в том, что после обработки запроса, вы можете получить данные о том, какой контроллер и какой экшен получит управление. Вы можете проверить, есть ли у пользователя права к этой странице и разрешить/запретить к ней доступ до того, как выполнятся действия данного action

Answer (score 0):

Если все Ваши странички отображаются через контроллеры и вьюхи (стандартный механизм для Yii) - добавьте проверку прав в базовый контроллер и все.

Comment: а если 20 ролей? с указанием в каждой роли доступных ссылок? прописывать каждой? возникла мысль фреймить содержимое страницы, сгенеренное Yii но без хэдера и футера

Comment: Если ролей много - проще проверять не роль, а действие (т.е.) есть действие "просмотр странички контакты", например. И это действие разрешается всем ролям. Тогда проверить стоит не роль, а именно действие.